# Integrating Mysql views with Laravel Models

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.3

I have multiple tables say Users , Location, terms and services i want to make a mysql view because every time i have to make a join statement for fetching the desired result. please help how to get it accomplished? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to create a view or read it Laravel?

CREATE VIEW vw_MyView AS

You could use Query Builder

```
   $rows = \DB::select('select * from vw_MyView');
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        var_dump($row->field);
    }
```